# Magento 2: Deprecated Functionality: Function ReflectionType::__toString() is deprecated

Tags: php, magento2

so I tried to execute the command 'php bin/magento setup:upgrade', but got the following error, even though everything worked fine in the morning:

```
Deprecated Functionality: Function ReflectionType::__toString() is deprecated in /usr/www/users/dlbbve/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-code/src/Reflection/ParameterReflection.php on line 85
```

After googling I found out that apparently the PHP v7.4 doesn't fully support M2 and I have to lower the PHP version to 7.3. I checked my php version in terminal and got 
'PHP 7.4.2 (cli)'. So I looked up my servers PHP setting and it should be set to 7.3.
And when I used the 'phpinfo()' command in a php file I got the PHP version 7.3 something back.

My question is why are there different PHP versions? What can have caused it.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With apache :

you should try to set php 7.3 version by running this command line :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3
```

and then

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: thanks, for the help, however I just use php73 in every command. Seems to work